# Why returned promise is empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use `.all` to do an action after all promise got resolved but when I return a promise its just empty.

I am appending all promises to `pushPromise` and later when I try to do `Promise.all(pushPromise)` then it wont work.

I tried to `console.log(pushPromise)` and it shows empty array. Why?

Thanks

```
var Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
var sftp = new Client();
var folderPromise = [];
var toServer = function(dir){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
        filePermission(dir, function(){
            getAllFiles(dir.replace(/\/$/, ''));
            console.log('Got all files');

            resolve();
        }); 
    }).then(function(done){
        arrayfolder.forEach(function(folder){
            folder = folder.replace(dir, '');
            //console.log(folder);
            folderPromise.push(sftp.mkdir(folder, true));
        });
        return Promise.all(folderPromise).then(function(){
            console.log('Folder added');
            return 'Done';
        });

    }).then(function() {
        return 'Done';
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return 'Not Done';
    });
}

var pushPromise = [];

connections.forEach(function(connection){
    var dir = getConnectionDir(connection);
    pushPromise.push(toServer(dir));
});

console.log(pushPromise); // return []

Promise.all(pushPromise).then(function(){
    console.log('All uploaded to server');
});
```

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(connections)` and post the result? My guess is that is empty

Comment: Does `getAllFiles` return result asynchronously? What is purpose of returning `"DONE"` twice at separate `.then()`?, and `resolve()` call at `.then()` chained to `Promise.all()?

Comment: No they are not. Also all `console.log` inside ` toServer ` are showing in sequence.

Comment: _"I tried to console.log(pushPromise) and it shows empty array"_ Where is `console.log()` where returned value from promise is logged at `javascript` at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 no `getAllFiles` is synchronous, and returning `done` just for example. There is a console log in it.

Comment: What is expected result? Is `sftp.mkdir(folder, true)` synchronous?

Comment: @guest271314 I have updated code. Thanks

Comment: @guest271314 `sftp.mkdir(folder, true)` returns promise object. when I console.log `folderPromise` it return array of promise

Comment: No value is resolved at initial `Promise()` at `toServer()` call? Only `"Done"` or `"Not Done"` appear to be returned from `toServer()`

Comment: as @FrankerZ said, `connections` must be an empty array, that's the only explanation

Comment: @guest271314 returning a string value in `resolve` but does not make any difference.

Comment: _"when I console.log `folderPromise` it return array of promise"_ If `folderPromise` contains an array of promises what are the values of the promises? _"returning a string value in `resolve` but does not make any difference."_ What does `result` log at `Promise.all(pushPromise).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
});`?

Comment: here is console.log when I run script:
`[]`
`All uploaded to server`
`Got all files`
`Folder added`
`Got all files`
`Folder added`
I think issue is due to `pushPromise`  is running without waiting for other promise to finish.

Comment: the `toServer` could be doing 7 kinds of wrong, but that's irrelevant, because the only way `pushPromise` could be an empty array is if the `connections.forEach` loop never gets run - which would mean `connections` is an empty array

Comment: No, `connections` have two items. and you can see console log in `toServer` output two times.

Comment: Where is `arrayfolder` defined?

Comment: _"and you can see console log in `toServer` output two time"_ What does `result` log at `Promise.all(folderPromise).then(function(result){
            console.log(result);
        });`?

Comment: Its defined by `getAllFiles` synchronously. and when I console log `arrayfolder` right after  calling `getAllFiles` it return list of files.

Comment: @guest271314 console.log return list of `[undefined, undefined.... ]`,

Comment: @user6571640 Does `folder = folder.replace(dir, '');` define `folder` as an empty string? or an invalid path? _"`sftp.mkdir(folder, true)` returns promise object. "_  Have you tried attaching `.catch()` to `sftp.mkdir(folder, true)` call?

Comment: What is expected result of `sftp.mkdir(folder, true)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem may be with `connections` returning an empty array. I tested locally and `pushPromise` is returning array of promises properly.